# Time series prediction / approximation in matlab

Tags: matlab, time-series, fft, linear-algebra, prediction

My question is how can I approximate / predict a discrete time series with a sum of cosine and sine terms with using FFT in matlab.

First step to predict the time series is to understand how to fit the sum of cosine and sine term to the time series. FFT of the time series gives the frequency at a certain timestep.

Tried to make a matrix A with the cosine and sine term with the certain frequency and define x as a matrix with the fourier coefficients and solve x = A \ b'  where b is the time series.

How to define the matrix A and x.

```matlab
b = eta_train;
t = t_train;

N = length(b);
Fs = 1 / 100;

frequencies = (0:N-1) * Fs / N;
B = fft(b);
alpha = real(B);

beta = -imag(B)

x = linspace(0, 2*pi, 1000);
A = diag(alpha.*cos(2*pi .*frequencies.*0.01.*x)) + 1i * diag(beta.*sin(2*pi .*frequencies.*x.*0.01));

x = A .\ b';
A = sum(diag(A));
figure;
plot(x, A)
```

Comment: It is unclear what you are asking. What is your training data? What is the input to your system? Are you using “train” and “predict” because this is a ML problem? The FFT usually doesn’t involve training or predicting. Somehow I think this question really is “what is the FFT and how do I interpret its output?” — in which case all you need to do is Google, it has been explained millions of times.

Comment: I want to fit a function to my time series and use it to predict the value in the next time step. The input data is surface evolution / water waves in time. I do not understand how to define the matrices..

Comment: So you want to *extrapolate*. You can do that using the FFT, sure, but it’ll just be as bad as any other method. “Prediction is hard, especially about the future”. But if your data really is periodic, you can extend it assuming periodicity. Fit a few sines as your model. Use any function fitting tool for that. Maybe [`fit`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/curvefit/fit.html)?

Comment: Exactly! I was thinking kind of a autoregression but using harmonic terms instead of linear ones to see if it fits better than the auto regressing model. But Im not sure how to.

Comment: The FFT is not the right tool for  that though. You could use it to get a good initial estimate for your sum of sines, but I wouldn't use those values directly to extrapolate.

Comment: Which matrices? The FFT doesn’t use any. Why don’t you edit your post to include what code you have so far, so that we all know what we’re referring to. It will make it easier to help you.

Comment: Why isent FFT a good option? What are the options?

Comment: The FFT fits a series of sines of fixed frequencies. If the sines in your data don't match those frequencies exactly, they'll be decomposed into many sines in a range of frequencies. It is better to just fit a custom model with a set of sine waves, if you can estimate how many of them you need. Then you get much more precise frequency estimates. For waves, I'd think that is a doable proposition.